# Get value property from table sapui5

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I want to delete data by row in my table sapui5 but have an error. I have table with id name "tableKelompokPeserta".

code:

```
   deleteButton2 : function(){
       var oTable = this.getView().byId("tableKelompokPeserta");

       oTable.attachRowSelectionChange(function(oEvent){

           var currentRowContext = oEvent.getParameter("rowContext");
           var selData = extModel.getProperty("template", currentRowContext);
           console.log(selData);
           sap.m.MessageToast.show(currentRowContext); 
       });         

   },

   onInit : function (){

        var router = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);

        var uri = "http://172.16.50.202:8081/id/co/taspen/joinDevelopment/modules/tks_mantab/service.xsjs?cmd=get";
        var jsonMod = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(uri,true);

        var oTable = this.getView().byId("tableKelompokPeserta");
        oTable.setModel(jsonMod);

        var oColumn1  = new sap.ui.table.Column({
            label : new sap.ui.commons.Label({
                text: "KODE KELOMPOK", 
                textAlign : "Center"}),
            template :  new sap.ui.commons.TextField().bindProperty("value", "KODE_KELOMPOK"), 
            sortProperty : "KODE_KELOMPOK",
            filterProperty : "KODE_KELOMPOK"
        });

        var oColumn2  = new sap.ui.table.Column({
            label : new sap.ui.commons.Label({
                text: "NAMA", 
                textAlign : "Center"}),
            template :  new sap.ui.commons.TextField().bindProperty("value", "NAMA"),   
            sortProperty : "NAMA",
            filterProperty : "NAMA"
        }); 

        var oColumn3  = new sap.ui.table.Column({
            label : new sap.ui.commons.Label({
                text: "MINIMAL USIA MASUK", 
                textAlign : "Center"}),
            template :  new sap.ui.commons.TextField().bindProperty("value", "MINIMAL_USIA_MASUK"),     
            sortProperty : "MINIMAL_USIA_MASUK",
            filterProperty : "MINIMAL_USIA_MASUK"
        });

        var oColumn4  = new sap.ui.table.Column({
            label : new sap.ui.commons.Label({
                text: "MAKSIMAL USIA MASUK", 
                textAlign : "Center"}),
            template :  new sap.ui.commons.TextField().bindProperty("value", "MAKSIMAL_USIA_MASUK"),
            sortProperty : "MAKSIMAL_USIA_MASUK",
            filterProperty : "MAKSIMAL_USIA_MASUK"
        });

        var oColumn5  = new sap.ui.table.Column({
            label : new sap.ui.commons.Label({
                text: "TERUSAN", 
                textAlign : "Center"}),
            template :  new sap.ui.commons.TextField().bindProperty("value", "TERUSAN"),                
            sortProperty : "TERUSAN",
            filterProperty : "TERUSAN"
        });

        var oColumn6 = new sap.ui.table.Column({
            label : "ACTION",
            template : new sap.ui.commons.Button({
                icon : "sap-icon://edit",
                tooltip : "{KODE_KELOMPOK}",
                press : function(){
                    var id = this.getTooltip();
                }

            })
        });         

        oTable.addColumn(oColumn1);
        oTable.addColumn(oColumn2);
        oTable.addColumn(oColumn3);
        oTable.addColumn(oColumn4);
        oTable.addColumn(oColumn5);
        oTable.addColumn(oColumn6);
        oTable.bindRows("/d/results");     

   }
```

I have 6 columns and I want to get "KODE_KELOMPOK" column selected row (single selection only). I want when click deletebutton2, I get "KODE_KELOMPOK" (from oColumn1). and how to disable multiple row in sapui5? Thank you.

Regards,

Bobby

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, in your `deleteButton2` event handler, use the `oEvent` object to get the row of the pressed delete button:

```
deleteButton2 : function(oEvent){
    var sValue = oEvent.getSource().getParent().getBindingContext().getProperty("KODE_KELOMPOK");
}
```

`sValue` will contain the value of the `KODE_KELOMPOK` model property for the selected row.

For your second question, list selection mode can be set using the `mode` property of the `List` control. Supported values can be found [here](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.ListMode.html). `SingleSelectMaster` seems to be good for you.